# How to convert custom Class(MTRequest) to JSON?

Tags: objective-c

This is the custom class and needed to serialize the id metadata which stores class:

```
@class MTRequestContext;
@class MTRequestErrorContext;

#import <MTProtoKit/MTRpcError.h>

@interface MTRequest : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) id internalId;

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSData *payload;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) id metadata;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) id (^responseParser)(NSData *);

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *decorators;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MTRequestContext *requestContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MTRequestErrorContext *errorContext;
@property (nonatomic) bool hasHighPriority;
@property (nonatomic) bool dependsOnPasswordEntry;
@property (nonatomic) bool passthroughPasswordEntryError;

@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^completed)(id result, NSTimeInterval completionTimestamp, MTRpcError *error);
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^progressUpdated)(float progress, NSUInteger packetLength);
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^acknowledgementReceived)();

@property (nonatomic, copy) bool (^shouldContinueExecutionWithErrorContext)(MTRequestErrorContext *errorContext);
@property (nonatomic, copy) bool (^shouldDependOnRequest)(MTRequest *anotherRequest);

- (void)setPayload:(NSData *)payload metadata:(id)metadata responseParser:(id (^)(NSData *))responseParser;

@end
```

Comment: I want to create json object generic type class    .I need to serialize id metadata(which stores Class).

Comment: Give solution on how i create generic JSON object from Custom class.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a method on that class that returns a dictionary.

So make your method -(NSDictionary*)getDictionary;

and in that just do

NSDictionary* dictionary = @{@"internalID": self.internalID} and so on

and return that dictionary in that method.

Hope that helps!

Comment: id metadata holds many classes as per request thats why i want to create it generic Please give me solution.